# Auto Completion not Working Visual studio unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've been working on a unity project recently and I opened my script editor (visual studio) and started coding, only to find that my auto completion was not working. so i tried to find out what was wrong and realized the thing on the top right said "Miscellaneous files" instead of "Assembly C-sharp", I had ran into this problem before and it was relatively easy to fix with a bit of googling, although this time it also said "file failed to load" I tried literally EVERYTHING google said to do.
and nothing was working.

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried already?

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! I doubt you are using that language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. the name of my game had parentheses, and visual studio wasn't able to load things with parentheses. I'm guessing most symbols would do the same thing. so if your game's name has some kind of symbol in it, try removing them and see if it works.